# Record video from webcam with jquery/flash directly in browser?

Tags: php, jquery, flash, video, webcam

I want to let users record video via webcam and then upload the recorded video to the site all through the browser.

Here is an example that works exactly how I want my site to work except it does not seem to capture video, just images.

http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/

Please let me know if there is a way I can customize this or if there is something else out there that I can use.

I want something standalone and don't want to rely on another service to accomplish this.

Thanks!

Comment: I know this question is old, but just in case someone comes across it. Browsers have made some progress since then and it is possible to do entirely client side, even without flash. Have a look at https://clipchamp.com, they are working on a plugin as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We've been looking for the same thing, but from my research, it appears there's no way to do it strictly through jquery and Flash without some back end help.

What I've found is three options:

1. Adobe Flash Media Server
2. Wowza Media Server
3. Red5 Media Server

There's advantages and disadvantages to all three. Flash and Wowza are not free, but have great documentation and support. Red5 is free, but the documentation can be lacking depending on what you're doing.

We just signed up for a free 180-day Developer license for Wowza and are currently evaluating that.

Comment: I can vouch that Wowza is very good for recording high quality video even over slow connections because of the way it waits for both the audio and video data (to sync it) from the client before writing it to disk.

Comment: @Martol1ni Wowza ended up working very well - we coupled it with the solution Octavian suggested - HDFVR and have been very happy with the results.

Comment: Where can i find a working example of Adobe Flash Media Server.. Pardon me Since I am new to this

Answer (score 0):

[HaxeVideo](http://code.google.com/p/haxevideo/) is an multithread FLV streaming server entirely written using the Haxe programming language.

And this link for information [Haxe programming language](http://haxe.org/).

But I found an easy way out for me. I have 2 options for you.

1. youtube api (Free) https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_upload_widget
2. http://nimbb.com/ (Not Free)

But if you want to try.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://hdfvr.com . It is a commercial video recording solution developed in Flash. It can record to both .flv and .mp4 files and when used with Wowza and the Wowza Transcoder it can record MP4 files with AAC audio and H.264 video.

It works with all 3 media servers in the top answer: Adobe Media Server, Wowza Media Server and Red5 Media Server .

Answer (score 0):

You had better to use a third party tool like red5 or wowza. I already implemented wowza with php. 
you can chech http://www.wowza.com/streaming/record. It is easy to implement and video recording is too good and fast. But it is not free.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a good helpful resource for further readers. [Click here](https://github.com/streamproc/MediaStreamRecorder)

Answer (score 0):

Wowza seems a good solution for recordings considering price/documentation&reliability ratio. Many users reported broken videos when trying to record with Red5.

This solution mentioned in Wowza Streaming Engine forums works with latest Wowza server.
http://www.wowza.com/forums/showthread.php?35683-Webcam-Video-Recorder-for-PHP-scripts

It's free to download and try so it could be a great method to test your setup and start such project.