# Record video and save it to php server

Tags: php, html, flash, video, webrtc

I had worked on a video-recording project using html5 but failed.I was able to view and take screenshot of video but not record it and send it to php.

Therefore, is flash a more easy and successful way? If yes, then how do i start? How do big sites like skype and google do it?  Any alternative.

Comment: This is highly opinionated question and does not really fit the format for SO...If you have a technical question, then ask that.

Comment: I want the best options

Comment: "best" is relative. You could easily do this with Flash, WebRTC, WebSockets, or a custom plugin. All are equally valid options and all are not super difficult to implement. Secondly, you ask numerous questions in your single question(about google and skype). Thirdly, you already asked this question about your "failure", it has only been up for 5 hours and you are already throwing in the towel on somebody helping you...

Answer (score 10):

There is [RecordRTC-to-PHP](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RecordRTC/RecordRTC-to-PHP) open-sourced project, recording both audio and video individually and pushing to server using traditional HTTP-POST mechanism.

There is a similar project: [RcordRTC-to-PHP-and-FFmpeg](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RecordRTC/PHP-and-FFmpeg), not only recording audio/video individually but also using ffmpeg on PHP side to merge both files in single WebM container.

You can use `ffmpeg-asm.js` to not only transcode but also merge inside the browser and POST just single mp4 file to PHP server. Try [a demo](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/ffmpeg/merging-wav-and-webm-into-mp4.html) to see how transcode/merge works.

You may like to try [MediaStreamRecorder.js](https://github.com/streamproc/MediaStreamRecorder) which has flash-fallback solutions as well.

Comment: [RecordRTC](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RecordRTC) is a server-less (entire client-side) JavaScript library can be used to record WebRTC audio/video media streams. It supports cross-browser audio/video recording.

Comment: Does recordrtc uses getusermedia() stuffs?

Comment: By default, RecordRTC uses getUserMedia but you can use captureStreamUntilEnded on firefox to record ogg or mp3 or mp4 or other supported formats. RecordRTC can also record your webpage activity e.g. https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/Canvas-Recording/

Comment: BTW, it seems that [canvas recording demo](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/Canvas-Recording/) has some bugs out of new RecordRTC updates. I'll fix it very soon.

Comment: Is this free?
Works on all browsers?
Able to click a image and save as .jpeg?
Record video and save as .mp4?

Comment: RecordRTC is [MIT-licenced](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/licence/) which means that it is totally free for any kind of usage: commercial or non-commercial. [Take-Snapshot](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/blob/master/RTCMultiConnection/Library/RTCMultiConnection-v1.7.js#L4069) feature has not been added in RecordRTC however you can easily add it yourself. You can find two [mp4-recording demos here](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/ffmpeg).

Comment: @Mauz Is there a similar project which does this with adobe flash?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK you need a Media server like the one from Adobe (or Red5/Wowza) to record video streams with flash.

Related older post with some alternative ideas:

[Record video from webcam with jquery/flash directly in browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278293/record-video-from-webcam-with-jquery-flash-directly-in-browser)

Comment: Here some links: http://www.adobe.com/products/adobe-media-server-extended.html [official adobe] http://www.wowza.com/ [commercial alternative] http://www.red5.org/ [free open source alternative]